# How fix size's limitation of MultipleLookupField?

Tags: 2010

I have a boring problem with MultipleLookupField component of SharePoint WebControls.

This component allow add items in parallel list, but saves just at maximum 10 items. And saves all items at a string field that has size just 255 characters.

You can see the reported problem right [here](http://www.sharepointanalysthq.com/2010/06/sharepoint-2007-when-to-use-look-up-columns-instead-of-the-choice-column-in-sharepoint/).

So, I need some solution that is possible add how many items the user put at list parallel list.

Has any way to increase or remove this limit?

If someone had a similar problem I really appreciate any orientation.

Thanks.

Comment: according to your reference (http://www.sharepointanalysthq.com/2010/06/sharepoint-2007-when-to-use-look-up-columns-instead-of-the-choice-column-in-sharepoint/) the multiple lookup field allows an unlimited number of choices.

Comment: Like I said, when this values is saved just 10 items or 255 characters it's stored.

Comment: Have you checked the “Allow Multiple Values” and “Allow unlimited length in document libraries” options

Comment: monteirobrena, unfortunately I am unable to duplicate your problem. I created a Lookup Column that allows multiple selections, and was able to add more than ten items with no problems. I then created a standard multiple choice field, and was able to select more than 10 items that had a total length of over 255 characters. Can you please provide more details? Thanks.

Comment: @Chloraphil I can add more 10 items but just saves the first 10. I'll do again and post the code. Thanks.